# Header not getting set for a HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, servlets, exception

Hey I am trying to implement a servlet where in case of an exception, I add a header to the response:

```
    catch (Exception e) {
                response.addHeader("ErrorCode", e.getErrorMessage());
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST,
                        e.getErrorMessage());
            }
```

and on the client side I store all the headers in an array:

```
    Header[] header=response.getAllHeaders();

    if(header.length>0)
    {
     errorMessage = header[0].getValue();
     //do this for all the six elements in the header[] array

    }
```

But in the response I cannot see the header with name `ErrorCode`. While debugging I can see that my servlet is throwing an exception. But on the client side I cannot see the header name/value. What can be the reson behind this? Should i use `setHeader()` instead of `addHeader()`? Does it matter in this case?

Comment: Exception doesn't have a method called `getErrorMessage`, which suggests this isn't your real code...

Comment: This function is implemented by my company. Yes the exception in the catch is not Exception e but its my comapnies custom exception. And we have an getErrorMessage function to get the error desc.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling...

```
response.setError();
response.reset();
```

...prior to adding your header.  I seem to remember having to do this when writing a custom error reporting valve for Tomcat once.

Comment: This won't matter because you're already calling `response.sendError(...)` after you add the header, which will set it to the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling flushBuffer() on the response.

Comment: it commits the response to the client. what does that exactly mean. Plus I am getting 6 headers like the content lenght/type, server name etc. Only when I explictly call addHeader(), that header is not present in the response at the client side.